How does the given statement restrict $x$ to just one member of the universe?
This question is from my discrete mathematics exam:

Let the universe comprise all guests at a party. We define the following open formulae:
$B(x)$: guest $x$ came to the party by bike
$C(x)$: guest $x$ came to the party by car
Using $x \ne y$ to mean "$x$ and $y$ are different elements of the universe", express the following statement in symbolic form:
All guests at the party came by bike except one, who came by car.

This is my teacher's answer:

$\exists x\forall y\Big( (x\ne y \to B(y)) ∧ (C(x) ∧ ¬ B(x))\Big).$

I do not understand how this statement limits $x$ to one guest. Is the answer simply wrong?
And if specifying $[C(x) ∧ ¬ B(x)]$ is because $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ are not mutually exclusive, then why did this not need to be specified for $y$ ?



All guests at the party came by bike except one, who came by car.


The given statement can be read as the conjunction of these two:

Someone did not come by bike and came by car;
everyone else came by bike (note that this is compatible with some guest having come by both bike and car—for instance, arriving in a fellow guest's car after their bike had broken down).

Symbolically:
$\exists x\Big( (¬Bx ∧ Cx) ∧ \forall y\, (y\ne x \to By) \Big),\tag1$ that is
$\exists x\forall y \Big( ¬Bx ∧ Cx ∧ (y\ne x \to By) \Big),\tag*{}$ as required:


$\exists x\forall y \Big( (x\ne y \to By) ∧ (Cx ∧ ¬ Bx)\Big).$



I do not understand how this statement limits $x$ to one guest.

Statement $(1)$ says that

$¬B(p) ∧ C(p),$ where $p$ is that particular guest,
while $B(x)$ is satisfied by everyone else (i.e., every $y$ such that $y\ne p).$


if specifying $(C(x) ∧ ¬ B(x))$ is because $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ are not mutually exclusive, then why did this not need to be specified for $y$ ?

The truth sets of $B(x)$ and $C(x)$ may indeed be non-disjoint; the given statement precludes their intersection only from containing $p,$ not from containing any of the other guests $y.$

Alternatively, the given statement can be read as

exactly one guest did not come by bike; this guest came by car.

Symbolically:
$\exists x\Big(Cx\land \forall y\,(y=x\leftrightarrow \lnot By)\Big),\tag*{}$ that is,
$\exists x\Big(Cx\land \lnot Bx\land \forall y\,(y\ne x\to By)\Big).\tag1$

A shorter answer to the title question: If there were two values, say $x_1$ and $x_2$, with the asserted property, then we'd have both $\neg B(x_1)$ and $\forall y\,(x_2\neq y\to B(y))$.  Since $x_1\neq x_2$, the second of these conclusions would imply (by taking $x_1$ as the value of $y$) that $B(x_1)$, contradicting the first conclusion.

In a "realistic" context it is clear that $B(y)\leftrightarrow \neg C(y)$ for every guest $y$. So your second quote can be simplified to $\exists x\forall y\left((y\neq x \to B(y))\land C(x)\right)$. However, if $B\leftrightarrow\neg C$ is not assumed, then you must include both $B$ and $C$ in the answer. Just as your teacher wrote, it may happen that some guests have arrived by bike and by car (which does not make sense). Then, if he specified it for $x$ (the guest who came by car), he should also have specified it for those guests $y$ who are not $x$: $$\exists x\forall y\left((y\neq x \to B(y)\land \neg C(y))\land C(x)\land \neg B(x)\right).$$

The given sentence says, of the guests other than the special one, that they came by bike. If you  haven't assumed $B(y)\leftrightarrow\neg C(y)$, then  these guests could have also arrived by car. So I don't see a reason for adding $\neg C(y)$ to the formula.

@AndreasBlass If you do not assume $B(y)\leftrightarrow \neg C(y)$, can you deduct $\neg C(y)$ from $\exists x \forall y((y\neq x\to B(y))\land C(x)\land \neg B(x))$?


All guests at the party came by bike except one

By itself, this tells us that one person did not come by bike:
$$ \exists x (\lnot B(x)). $$
It also tells us that every other guest did come by bike, so once we have identified a guest $x$ who did not come by bike, if $y$ is any other guest then they came by bike:
$$ \exists x ((\lnot B(x)) \land (x \neq y \rightarrow B(y))). $$
This is sufficient to express the statement "all guests at the party came by bike except one" because we defined the entire universe as the set of guests at that party.
If the universe were larger, we'd need to include a predicate that said something about whether $y$ was a guest at the party.
The expression $\lnot B(x)$ is still essential here, because if we wrote only
$$ \exists x (x \neq y \rightarrow B(y)) $$
then we could satisfy the statement in a world where all the guests came by bike, provided that there was in fact a party and there was at least one guest (that is, the universe is not empty).
Now let's append to the original statement,

... who came by car.

So when we identify $x$ as the guest who did not come by bike, we must also say that they came by car, $C(x)$.
$$ \exists x ((\lnot B(x)) \land (x \neq y \rightarrow B(y)) \land C(x)). $$
Strictly speaking, there is nothing in the problem statement that says $\lnot B(x)$ necessarily follows from $C(x)$. So if we have only
$$ \exists x ((x \neq y \rightarrow B(y)) \land C(x)) $$
we don't know that there was someone who didn't arrive by bike.
We know only that someone arrived by car (and maybe also by bike) and that everyone else arrived by bike (and maybe also by car).
That said, the presentation of the problem in natural language is a little confusing, because in real life it is likely that when describing how people came to a party we would give exclusive descriptions, that is, if we say someone came by bike it means that a bicycle was the only means of transportation they used. One thing we can learn from logic exercises like this one is that we make such assumptions without really thinking about them; reducing things to predicate logic forces us to think about those assumptions and requires us to make them explicit if we are going to use them.
